# groupby two columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'sym': list('aabaabab'), 'dir':[0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1], 'price': [100, 101, 102, 110, 120, 125, 200, 250]})

   dir  price sym
0    0    100   a
1    0    101   a
2    0    102   b
3    1    110   a
4    0    120   a
5    1    125   b
6    1    200   a
7    1    250   b
```

I want to groupby `sym` and a set of 0 and 1(not sure if it is the right term to say it ! ). 
My desired outcome looks like this:

```
   dir  price sym
0    0    100   a
1    0    101   a
3    1    110   a
   dir  price sym
4    0    120   a
6    1    200   a
   dir  price sym
2    0    102   b
5    1    125   b
7    1    250   b
```

each time `dir` become 0 in each `sym` I want a new group with the 1s after that 0

Comment: can the second group be clubbed to the first? since both are `a`

Comment: no. this is the exact outcome that  I need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `cumsum` create another helpkey , then `groupby`

```
df['helpkey']=df.groupby('sym').apply(lambda x : ((x['dir']==1)&(x['dir'].shift(-1)==0)).shift().fillna(0).cumsum()).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
d={x: y for x , y in df.groupby(['helpkey','sym'])}
```

---

```
for x , y in df.groupby(['helpkey','sym']):
 print(y)

  sym  dir  price helpkey
0   a    0    100       0
1   a    0    101       0
3   a    1    110       0
  sym  dir  price helpkey
2   b    0    102       0
5   b    1    125       0
7   b    1    250       0
  sym  dir  price helpkey
4   a    0    120       1
6   a    1    200       1
```